# How can I translate the datepicker of handsontable?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I am using the handsontable. I have a date column that I use the datepicker.

How can I translate the week and month names to pt-br?

Answer (score 0):

according to the handsontable docs, it uses [Pikaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday) to show the UI for the calendar.
Maybe follow pikadays instructions to change the names according to your language https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday#internationalization

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

According to Handsontable docs, you can use datePickerConfig property and set configurations of Pickaday.
https://handsontable.com/docs/6.2.2/demo-date.html
https://github.com/Pikaday/Pikaday#configuration

For example,
In your column settings:

```
    },
        {
          data: 'dateLabelExample',
          type: 'date',
          dateFormat: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
          correctFormat: true,
          defaultDate: '2020/10/10',
          allowEmpty: false,
          renderer: this.dateValidation,
          datePickerConfig: this.constants.CalendarSpanish
        },
        {
```

Date settings declaration:

```
readonly CalendarSpanish = {
      i18n: {
        previousMonth: 'Mes anterior',
        nextMonth: 'Siguiente Mes',
        months: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
        weekdays: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles ', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
        weekdaysShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab']
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it inside the datePickerConfig prop inside the column that is 'date' type, and then you will be able to use the same configuration as the [Pickday](https://github.com/Pikaday/Pikaday)

Your code will look like the following:

```
 <HotColumn
      data={"field_name"}
      title={"field display name"}
      type="date"
      datePickerConfig={{
        showWeekNumber: true,
        i18n: {
          previousMonth: "Mês Anterior",
          nextMonth: "Próximo Mês",
          months: [
            "Janeiro",
            "Fevereiro",
            "Março",
            "Abril",
            "Maio",
            "Junho",
            "Julho",
            "Agosto",
            "Setembro",
            "Outubro",
            "Novembro",
            "Dezembro",
          ],
          weekdays: [
            "Domingo",
            "Segunda",
            "Terça",
            "Quarta",
            "Quinta",
            "Sexta",
            "Sábado",
          ],
          weekdaysShort: ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sab"],
        },
      }}
    />
```

If you pretend to do the same configuration in multiple columns I suggest that you create a constant and import it wherever you need it.